Can this $\zeta(2n)$ formula be simplified?
For $n \geq 1 $, the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(2n)$ can be expressed as:
$$
\zeta(2n) = \frac{\pi^{2n} \cdot 2^{2n-1} \cdot \left(1 + \left\lfloor \frac{2(2^{2n} - 1)(2n)!}{2^{2n-1} \pi^{2n}} \sum_{k=1}^{3n} k^{-2n} \right\rfloor \right)}{(2(2^{2n} - 1)) \cdot (2n)!}
$$
WolframAlpha shows this alternate form
$$
\zeta(2n) = \frac{4^{n-1} \pi^{2n} \left( 1 + \left\lfloor 4^{1-n} (4^n - 1) \pi^{-2n} (2n)! \sum_{k=1}^{3n} \frac{1}{k^{2n}} \right\rfloor \right)}{(4^n - 1) (2n)!}
$$
Is there a way to further simplify that formula?
Examples

For $n = 1$ WolframAlpha:
$$
  \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
  $$

For $n = 6$ WolframAlpha:
$$
  \zeta(12) = \frac{691 \pi^{12}}{638512875}
  $$

For $n = 7$ WolframAlpha:
$$
  \zeta(14) = \frac{2 \pi^{14}}{18243225}
  $$


References
Particular values of the Riemann zeta function
An "exact" formula for the m-th Bernoulli number
What is the simplest way to get Bernoulli numbers?

As you implicitly acknowledge in your references, this is really about finding a formula for Bernoulli numbers. Wikipedia has a number of methods to calculate them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Yep, originally I was looking for a denominator formula for $\zeta(2n)$ (similar to the Von Staudt-Clausen Theorem for Bernoulli numbers) but then ran into issues. So, I refocused on $\zeta(2n)$ when I learned about Chowla and Hartung.

The finite sum within the floor function is expressible as a generalized harmonic number: $H_{3n,,2n}$. Given that Wolfram Alpha only manages to give an algebraic manipulation, I doubt that further simplification is possible, especially with the floor function.
